# Validating ADC data through USB

Tags: usb, microcontroller, adc, cdc, nrf52

In our application we are sending ADC data(240 bytes) to host computer through USB at full speed and using Serial application like (teraterm/minicom/Docklet) to validate the data, but we are facing the issue of data loss.

We are not getting where the issue is weather the seral application is not able to handle the incoming data or is there any limitations at controller side operating at USB full speed?

Microcontroller - NRF52840

USB class - CDC ACM

Best regards
Sagar

Comment: Given the limited information, it's almost impossible to help you. There are so many things that could go wrong. I strongly suggest you post a minimal, reproducible code example.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you entirely disable (temporarily) the ADC function and only have the microcontroller send a counting sequence to verify the known pattern is transferred without loss to the PC side. If the pattern is detected without loss, then re-enable the ADC function, but still only send the counting sequence and test again. If data is missing, then the problem is most likely the ADC function is causing a timing condition (such as blocking the CPU too long).